# run .class file on S60 phone

Tags: java, java-me, symbian, s60

How do I make .class files, that I created using Java, run on an S60 phone?

Answer (score 2):

If you used Java ME it should work if you made a jar/jad file. However there are reasons why it could not be working see nokia for [more info](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Why_Doesn%27t_My_MIDlet_Run%3F)

Comment: aha! For mobile dev you should use a Java ME version. Try to convert your project to ME, set an Java ME on the classpath in your IDE instead of jdk6.0 and fix any incompatibilities and it should work.